# Using newly created field in ON of a Join

Tags: sql

I am wanting to clean up a dirty name and then use that newly cleaned name in a `JOIN` statement but SQL is giving the error:

```
Invalid column name clean_name
```

My code is as follows:

```
select clean_title,
             clean_name = left(ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name)), charindex(' ',ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name)), charindex(' ',ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name))) + 1))
             from all_names as an
             inner join on locationdatabase as ld
             on an.clean_name = ld.[name]
```

Is it possible to 'use' this newly created field in the join statement in such a way?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use that name in a `JOIN` as it doesn't exist when the `JOIN` is evaluated. You could use a `CTE` to work around it:

```
with cte as (
  select clean_title,
         clean_name = left(ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name)), charindex(' ',ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name)), charindex(' ',ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name))) + 1))
  from all_names as an
)
select *
from cte
join locationdatabase ld
on cte.clean_name = ld.[name]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an aliased temporary table table. Quick Example (something like):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT clean_title,
          left(ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name)), charindex(' ', ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name)), charindex(' ', ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name))) + 1)) AS clean_name
   FROM all_names) an
INNER JOIN ON locationdatabase AS ld ON an.clean_name = ld.[name]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for cannot be done in SQL. The join conditions are evaluated before the `select` clause, s the expression cannot be used in there.

One solution is to repeat the expression (likely, your database will optimize it and don't compute it twice).

Or you can use a subquery:

```
select 
    an.clean_title,
    an.clean_name
from 
    (
        select 
            left(ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name)), charindex(' ',ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name)), charindex(' ',ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name))) + 1))
                as clean_name,
            clean_title
        from all_names 
    ) as an
    inner join on locationdatabase as ld on an.clean_name = ld.name
```

This assumes that `clean_title` comes from table `all_names`. You should get use to always qualify your colmumn names with the table name (or alias) it belongs to, so the query is self-explanatory about the data structure it operates on.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax suggests SQL Server, which supports `APPLY` for lateral joins.

These are a powerful construct and let you define columns in the `FROM` clause -- which makes logic sense.  For instance, if `dirty_name` is in `all_names`, then:

```
select clean_title, vd.clean_name = 
from all_names an cross apply
     (values (left(ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name)),
                   charindex(' ',
                             ltrim(rtrim(dirty_name)), 
                             charindex(' ', 
                                       ltrim(rtrim( dirty_name))
                                      ) + 1
                            )
                         )
                  )
             )
      ) v(clean_name) join
      locationdatabase ld
      on v.clean_name = ld.[name]
```